# how made token of || in alex

Tags: haskell, token, lexer, happy

I'm new at Haskell and Alex.
I'm trying to make tokens of operators in Lexer.x

here is an example of my code

```
    \<=                           { \s -> TLE       }
    \==                           { \s -> TEQ       }
    \/=                           { \s -> TNEQ      }
    \&&                           { \s -> TAND      }
```

but when I wrote

```
    \||                           { \s -> TOR       }
```

I got a parse error on this line
How I should make token for || ?

Comment: Why not `"||" { \s -> TOR }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string literals to prevent escaping all characters, so you can use:

```
    "||"                           { \s -> TOR       }
```